# Psycopg2 Error installing Odoo 13 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: odoo, psycopg2, ubuntu-20.04, odoo-13

I'm trying to install Odoo 13 on Ubuntu 20.04, I have followed different procedures to install it like [this one](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-13-on-ubuntu-20-04/) for example, but I always got this **psycopg2** error (below this paragraph) when I reach the step of installing the components of the requirements.txt, and this error occurs only on python virtual environment.

Error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/odoo/odoo-venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7jyb6cog/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7jyb6cog/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-7c07yrdu
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7jyb6cog/psycopg2/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/opt/odoo/odoo-venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
     35 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.

  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.

  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
```

I have tried to install different versions of the psycopg2 manually without success.
If I don't use the virtual environment, there is no error and the installation process is totally successful.

Comment: Have you tried installing the **libpq-dev** package? (sudo apt-get install libpq-dev).

Comment: Hi Alonso, yes, libpq-dev was installed before trying to install the pyscopg2.

Hi Kenly, I'm sorry, maybe I was not clear, I meant I tried to install it manually but it also failed.

Thank you, for your comments.

Comment: Install `psycopg2-binary` instead as mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip install psycopg2-binary` for ubuntu and `pip install psycopg2` for windows

Comment: Thank you and @maurice-meyer too, installing psycopg2-binary solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Odoo13 along with Python 3.8 was kinda Problematic with many packages Including psycopg2 , Pillow , Python-ldap etc.It took me sometimes but i was able to run it with python 3.8 on 20.04
I changed the  requirment.txt file a bit, And watch my github link -

https://github.com/tanvirahmedkhan74/Installing-Odoo13-on-Ubuntu20.04-with-Python-3.8.git

Replace the requirments.txt file with the given one on the github

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

I ran the above command before installing from req.txt. In odoo14 community it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

odoo in ubuntu20 with option to connect custom asddons repo
https://github.com/jerichoruz/odoo-instal-sh

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score -2):

first install Pillow
`pip3 install pillow`
than install psycopg2 by installing
`sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev`
verify if pg_config is installed by running
`pg_config --version`
if not add it to the path
`export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/X.Y/bin/:$PATH`
after that
`pip install psycopg2`
next remove psycopg2 and pillow packagers from requirements.txt
and rerun
`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`